# OpenAI Gym rendering problem on M1 silicon chip

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, rendering, apple-m1, openai-gym

I am having trouble rendering an OpenAI gym environment on my M1 Pro.
The same code works very well on Linux notebook. I am using Anaconda with a virtual environment, virtual kernel(ipykernel). I found that a 'python' window(which seems to be the rendering screen) pops up, but would not be displayed. I could use the Linux VM, but I am curious the M1 chip is not suitable for running Gym environments.

The following is the code and error message.

```
typimport numpy as np
import gym

env=gym.make('FrozenLake-v1')
env.reset()
env.render()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 9
      7 env=gym.make('FrozenLake-v1') #or 'FrozenLake-v1' depending on your PC
      8 env.reset()
----> 9 env.render()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/core.py:329, in Wrapper.render(self, *args, **kwargs)
    325 def render(
    326     self, *args, **kwargs
    327 ) -> Optional[Union[RenderFrame, List[RenderFrame]]]:
    328     """Renders the environment."""
--> 329     return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/wrappers/order_enforcing.py:51, in OrderEnforcing.render(self, *args, **kwargs)
     46 if not self._disable_render_order_enforcing and not self._has_reset:
     47     raise ResetNeeded(
     48         "Cannot call `env.render()` before calling `env.reset()`, if this is a intended action, "
     49         "set `disable_render_order_enforcing=True` on the OrderEnforcer wrapper."
     50     )
---> 51 return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/wrappers/env_checker.py:53, in PassiveEnvChecker.render(self, *args, **kwargs)
     51 if self.checked_render is False:
     52     self.checked_render = True
...
    295 ), "Something went wrong with pygame. This should never happen."
    297 if self.clock is None:
    298     self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

AssertionError: Something went wrong with pygame. This should never happen.e here
```

I also tried installing 'stable-baselines3', but it made no changes.